# In codiginetor what so ever user can type in url but it should call default controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my codeigniter project if i run my localhost is like localhost/project name/typed what so ever i want to call default controller

Answer (score 2):

In your application/config/routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'controllername';
$route['(:any)'] = 'controllername';
```

There are other possible options here, but this will send anything to your default controller.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your routes file

```
./application/config/routes.php
```

And add

```
$route['(:any)'] = "controller";
```

This will match all routes.

Documentation [here.](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: Default controller set. But user want to redirected to default controller all url.

Comment: yes thanks for that.after that  next my anchor text means href this is    effected means some how it does not show exact page. first time i want like what you guys prescribed like only but it should not effected any where else in the project i think for that $route['(:any)'] = 'controllername'; used once in the project for that what should i do

Comment: dear kenzo can you tell the other possibility